# dbf2mysql not inserting records

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, dbf

I am using dbf2mysql library http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/dbf2mysql.1.html to port some data to mysql, but when i try to view the inserted records nothing is inserted.

Here is the command I am running:

```
$ dbf2mysql -vvv -q -h localhost -P password -U root smb/C_clist.DBF -d opera_dbf -t pricelists -c
Opening dbf-file smb/C_clist.DBF
dbf-file: smb/C_clist.DBF - Visual FoxPro w. DBC, MySQL-dbase: opera_dbf, MySQL-table: pricelists
Number of records: 12
Name         Length Display  Type
-------------------------------------
CL_CODE               8     0     C
CL_DESC              30     0     C
CL_CURR               3     0     C
CL_FCDEC              1     0     N
Making connection to MySQL-server
Dropping original table (if one exists)
Building CREATE-clause
Sending create-clause
CREATE TABLE pricelists (CL_CODE varchar(8) not null,
    CL_DESC varchar(30) not null,
    CL_CURR varchar(3) not null,
    CL_FCDEC int not null)

fields in dbh 4, allocated mem for query 279, query size 139
Inserting records
Inserting record 0
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/d2mygo04TM' REPLACE INTO table pricelists fields terminated by ',' enclosed by ''''
Closing up....
```

then in mysql, the tables are created with the correct fields types, but no data:

```
mysql> use opera_dbf;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> describe pricelists;
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| CL_CODE  | varchar(8)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| CL_DESC  | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| CL_CURR  | varchar(3)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| CL_FCDEC | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.13 sec)

mysql> select * from pricelists;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the -q option and it works

-q     dbf2mysql: "Quick" mode.  Inserts data via temporary file  using
              'LOAD  DATA  INFILE'  MySQL statement.  This increased insertion
              speed on my PC 2-2.5 times.  Also note that during  whole  'LOAD
              DATA' affected table is locked.